# python - list all inner functions of a function?

Tags: python, nested, built-in

In python you can do `fname.__code__.co_names` to retrieve a list of functions and global things that a function references. If I do `fname.__code__.co_varnames`, this includes inner functions, I believe.

Is there a way to essentially do `inner.__code__.co_names` ? by starting with a string that looks like `'inner'`, as is returned by `co_varnames`?

Comment: Is this a one level thing or you want nested functions as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can inspect the code object because inner functions are lazy, and their code-objects are only created just in time.  What you probably want to look at instead is the ast module.  Here's a quick example:

```
import ast, inspect

# this is the test scenario
def function1():
    f1_var1 = 42
    def function2():
        f2_var1 = 42
        f2_var2 = 42
        def function3():
            f3_var1 = 42

# derive source code for top-level function
src = inspect.getsource(function1)

# derive abstract syntax tree rooted at top-level function
node = ast.parse(src)

# next, ast's walk method takes all the difficulty out of tree-traversal for us
for x in ast.walk(node):
    # functions have names whereas variables have ids,
    # nested-classes may all use different terminology
    # you'll have to look at the various node-types to
    # get this part exactly right
    name_or_id = getattr(x,'name', getattr(x,'id',None))
    if name_or_id:
        print name_or_id
```

The results are: function1, function2, f1_var1, function3, f2_var1, f2_var2, f3_var1.  Obligatory disclaimer: there's probably not a good reason for doing this type of thing.. but have fun :)

Oh and if you only want the names of the inner functions?

```
print dict([[x.name,x] for x in ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(some_function))) if type(x).__name__=='FunctionDef'])
```

Comment: Good thinking. This would fail if running from a `pyc`, but I guess that's unusual.

Comment: Thank you, this does look like what I would be looking for. The reason I'm doing it is because I'm making an attempt at doing function traces, and I want to include inner functions in that.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.4+ you can get the names using [`dis.get_instructions`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions). To support nested functions as well you need to recursively loop over each code object you encounter:

```
import dis
import types

def get_names(f):
    ins = dis.get_instructions(f)
    for x in ins:
        try:
            if x.opcode == 100 and '<locals>' in next(ins).argval\
                                              and next(ins).opcode == 132:
                yield next(ins).argrepr
                yield from get_names(x.argval)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

**Demo:**

```
def func():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    print ('foo')
    class A:
        def method(self):
            pass
    def f1():
        z = 3
        print ('bar')
        def f2():
            a = 4
            def f3():
                b = [1, 2, 3]
    def f4():
        pass

print(list(get_names(func)))
```

**Outputs:**

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
```