# Python: is there a way to list all the functions defined inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a function that contains definitions of some other functions. Is
there a way to list all the functions defined inside a function?

For example, if there is a function `f` defined as below, how can I list
all the functions defined within `f`?

```py
def f(x):
    def g(y):
        return y

    def h(z):
        return z

    return x
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609867/python-list-all-inner-functions-of-a-function may be relevant?

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234672/1682419 ? For interactive use, look at the Structure view in an editor like PyCharm.