# Add decorator to all functions and class methods including nested functions

Tags: python

Lets say I have a file structure like this:

```
root
  dir1
    class1.py
  dir2
    class2.py
  main.py
```

**class1.py:**

```
class class1():
  def func1(self):
    print('class1.func1')
    def inner_func():
      print("class1.func1.inner_func")
    inner_func()
  def func2(self):
    print('class1.func2')
```

**class2.py:**

```
def func_from_class2():
  print("func_from_class2")
  def inner_func():
    print("func_from_class2.inner_func")
  inner_func()

class class2():
  def func1(self):
    print('class2.func1')
    def inner_func():
      print("class2.func1.inner_func")
    inner_func()
  def func2(self):
    print('class2.func2')
```

**main.py:**

```
import inspect
import sys
sys.path.append(".")

from dir1.class1 import class1
from dir2 import class2

def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         func_name = ""
         if inspect.ismethod(func):
             func_name = f"{func.__self__.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
         else:
             func_name = func.__name__
               
        print(f"decorator = {func_name}")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper


def decorate_all_functions_and_methods(module):
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction):
        setattr(module, name, my_decorator(obj))
        for fname, fobj in inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.isfunction):
            setattr(fobj, fname, my_decorator(fobj))
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass):
        for method_name, method in inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.ismethod):
            setattr(obj, method_name, my_decorator(method))
            for fname, fobj in inspect.getmembers(method, inspect.isfunction):
                setattr(fobj, fname, my_decorator(fobj))
        for nclass_name, nclass in inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.isclass):
            for method_name, method in inspect.getmembers(nclass, inspect.ismethod):
                setattr(nclass, method_name, my_decorator(method))
                for fname, fobj in inspect.getmembers(method, inspect.isfunction):
                    setattr(fobj, fname, my_decorator(fobj))



decorate_all_functions_and_methods(class1)
decorate_all_functions_and_methods(class2)



class1_obj = class1()
print('-----------------')
class1_obj.func1()
print('-----------------')
class1_obj.func2()
print('-----------------')

class2_obj = class2.class2()
print('-----------------')
class2_obj.func1()
print('-----------------')
class2_obj.func2()
print('-----------------')

class2.func_from_class2()
```

The above example seems to not work for nested functions.
I want to decorate all functions and methods from each module, including all methods from multiple classes in the same module, including all functions and nested functions.

The decorator should print the name of the function with keywork "decorator" so I know the decorator have been added to that function.

**Idealy it would be if the main.py can find all modules from all folders without importing them manually, some kind of automation if it is possible**

Comment: I think the problem you're running into is that the inner functions are in fact not members of the class, and do not exist until the outer function/method is called and the `def` statement is executed.  The inner function then stops being defined when the outer function finishes executing, although the outer function may return a <function> object representing the inner function.    Calling `inspect.getmembers(class1.func1)` outputs a lot of built-ins, but doesn't include innerfunc.  You may need to use the `ast` module instead of the `inspect` module to accomplish your goals.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609867/python-list-all-inner-functions-of-a-function - especially the accepted answer

Comment: @nigh_anxiety thank you for your thoughs. Then I'm afraid it is not possible to decorate the nested functions if they stops being defined when outer function finishes, like you suggested, but hope that there is a way :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need nested functions?  I have yet to find something they do that nothing else can get done, besides hiding.  Besides a function factory/closure scenario, where they get returned? But in that case you can decorate them on the way out.  By now, I mostly see them as a code smell and your issue is yet another reason.